# Storing value as variable, then adding to array. Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

My question is about performance, specifically in Javascript (Jquery).

Let's say I  want to store the value of 100 `html` input boxes in an array. Is it more efficient to store each value in a variable and then add to the array like this;

```
var x0 = $('#input0').val();
var x1 = $('#input1').val();
...
var x99 = $('#input99').val();

var myValues = new Array();
myValues[0] = x0;
myValues[1] = x1; 
...
myValues[99] = x99;
```

Or combine the steps like this?

```
var myValues = new Array();
myValues[0] = $('#input0').val();
myValues[1] = $('#input1').val();
...
myValues[99] = $('#input99').val();
```

Other things to consider besides performance?

Comment: I believe it would be more performant to put them all directly in the array, although I haven't tested it. However, you can make the code much simpler by giving all the elements a common class and building the array with `map()`. It would most likely be faster too.

Comment: even if you don't set a common class you could find the way to target all an loop

Comment: the question arises, what do you do after collecting?

Comment: "Other things to consider besides performance?" yes, readability for future developers.

Comment: @castis That was my thought as well. Part of the reason I have to consider using the first method over the second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Second case is more efficient in performance as compared to first one.**

`First case` create all those 100 variable and initialize them (inputs) and then 
 assign to the array.

`Second case` direct initialize them (inputs) to the array.

Test: If we count one initialization as 1 cost of time, then first case is doing it in `200 cost.` where second is doing `100 cost.`

[Help here!](https://www.cs.sfu.ca/~ggbaker/zju/math/complexity.html)

Comment: While this makes sense, with today's computing power, is there a difference between `100` and `200 cost`?

Comment: Of course! lets say 1 initialization takes 1 second. which shows first takes 200 seconds and Second takes it 100 seconds to complete the task.

Comment: @blackandorangecat , if you think this helped you please mark as resolved.